# WPF C# Global disable of RecognizesAccessKey for all controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a c# WPF application with a lot of different control types. I simply want the content for these controls displayed AS IS with no auto-underscore-stripping for the entire application. I've seen fixes for individual controls by altering the control template which work but is there a way to achieve this for all controls in the application at once instead of multiple template modification?

```
<ContentPresenter
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
              RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

For me it worked out, that in a global resource XAML of my code, I overwrite the standard-style for the ContentPresenter like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="RecognizesAccessKey" Value="False" />
</Style>
```